# How can a generic endpoint be created to accommodate seven different types?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, type-conversion, endpoint

Hi I'm trying to create generic endpoint to allow all these types and the name of the most property because for some type in db I have 2 cells (date1,date2). I'm trying to use T type, but when I call endpoint I get 404. Later I need knowledge about type to update correct cell in db. I don't know, maybe it's just better to create seven endpoints for each type. What's best practice? I've seen some solution with Jobject but it's hard to cast to object.

```
FirstEnum?
SecondEnum?
DateTime? GenericDate1
DateTime? GenericDate2
String?
bool?
int? GenericInt1
int? GenericInt2
decimal?
```

Endpoint to allow all these type:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateData<T>(long id, [FromBody] T value) 
{
    var result = await _dataService.UpdateData(id, value);
    if (!result)
        return NotFound();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Save to db, just part to show what I mean:

```cs
private async Task UpdateData(T newValue)
{
    switch (newValue)
    {
        case FirstEnum first:
            existingDataPoint.FirstEnum = first;
            break;
        case SecondEnum secondEnum :
            existingDataPoint.SecondEnum = secondEnum ;
            break;
        case bool genericBool:
            existingDataPoint.GenericBool = genericBool;
            break;
        case DateTime genericDate when newValue.Name == "GenericDate1":
            existingDataPoint.GenericDate1 = genericDate;
            break;
        case DateTime genericDate when newValue.Name == "GenericDate2":
            existingDataPoint.GenericDate2 = genericDate;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't use generic methods as controller mehods for routing. Instead make a non-generic method, that takes a (non-abstract) base class. When your incoming data is JSON, this base class can have a property marked with the `AdditionalDataAttribute`, which contains all values which don't match a base class property. Then write a converter that takes this base class instance and returns - depending on the given values - the concrete derived class instance. This can then be handled by switch case and do whatever needed.

Comment: you mean just create object     public class UpdateData
    {
        public string NameObject { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    } and then parse value depends of  NameObject  ?

Comment: You also need a container to store all json data, that doesn't match any property. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: Ok, thanks. Probably that's the only way. the bad thing is I can't use fluentValidation before I hit the endpoint, but I won't even be able to do that with T

Comment: Yes, for fluent validation you have to create different route endpoints for each specialized type to be processed within the middleware. Or you run within the controller the converter for the specialized type and afterwards call the corresponding validator manually as [described here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#manual-validation).